# mysqli bind parameter error

Tags: php, mysqli

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT x, y FROM users WHERE x > ( ?  - 10) AND x< ( ? + 10 ) AND y> ( ? - 10 ) AND y<( ? + 10 ) ")){

            $stmt->bind_param('ii', $x , $y); 
            $stmt->execute();
```

How do I make this code work without getting the error

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in...

I had it like this and it actually worked: `($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT x, y FROM users WHERE x>$x-10 AND x<$x+10 AND y>$y-10 AND y<$y+10 ")`
but I was getting the same "Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters" error since I wasn't really using any of the binded parameters of course.

Comment: You have 4 parameters but are only binding 2 of them. you have to bind all 4 of them even if it means repeating the same variable.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks this worked I just changed it into `$stmt->bind_param('iiii', $x, $x,$y, $y);`, post it as an answer and i'll accept it for correct answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind all parameters. I suggest you do this:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT x, y FROM users WHERE x > (?-10) AND x < (?+10) AND y > (?-10) AND y < (?+10)")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('iiii', $x, $x , $y, $y); 
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: This actually throws the following error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /var/www/html/scripts/move.php:20\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n

Comment: @Asgarnian I guess that makes sense. Do what you were originally planning to. (Updated)

Answer (score 3):

Solution (with some code refactor as a bonus :)).

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `x`, `y` FROM `users` WHERE `x` > ( ?  - 10) AND `x` < ( ? + 10 ) AND `y` > ( ? - 10 ) AND `y` <( ? + 10 )");
if( $stmt )
{
    $stmt->bind_param('iiii', $x , $x, $y , $y); 
    $stmt->execute();
}
```